# how to get YouTube video id from image thumbnail source, and set as an iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, src

So if the image tag is

```
<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LL0Y4MZ45bo/0.jpg" class="youtubeimg"></img>
```

I don't know how to extract the YouTube video id (`LL0Y4MZ45bo`) from the thumbnail image src and then apply it to an iframe.

currently i have 100% working, which applys the src to the iframe. but what i dont know how to do is get the id from the img tags in this case `LL0Y4MZ45bo` and add it to the youtube embed src http://www.youtube.com/embed/`LL0Y4MZ45bo`

```
<iframe src="" class="youtubeiframe"></iframe>

<script>
$(".youtubeiframe").attr({ 
  src: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO-ID-EXTRACTED-FROM-THUMBNAIL-SRC",
});
</script>
```

so how can I extract id from the img and apply to iframe src?

Comment: From now on you need to use it to extract thumbnail image from YouTube video ID.
                                                         
https://img.youtube.com/vi/{VIDEO_ID}/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extracts the [YouTube ID using a Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830596/what-type-of-id-does-youtube-use-for-their-videos), I made the assumption that it would be a minimum of eleven characters as the [first YouTube Video ID](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw) has 11.

```
<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LL0Y4MZ45bo/0.jpg" class="youtubeimg"></img>
<iframe src="" class="youtubeiframe"></iframe>

<script>
    $(function (){
        var youtubeid = $(".youtubeimg").attr("src").match(/[\w\-]{11,}/)[0];
        $(".youtubeiframe").attr({ 
              src: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + youtubeid,
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works, however the [YouTube Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html) may provide you with a more stable solution to loading that iFrame, in the future once it becomes stable I would recommend the [YouTube iFrame API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html)

Comment: @user1010031 Yeah, absolutely. You mind marking it as answered?

Comment: i have one more query. is there something to say if <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LL0Y4MZ45bo/0.jpg" class="youtubeimg"></img> or the class .youtubeimg is not present on the page do not display .youtubeiframe the class for the iframe?

Comment: `$(function (){
     if($(".youtubeimg").length){
         var youtubeid = $(".youtubeimg").attr("src").match(/[\w\-]{11,}/)[0];
         $(".youtubeimg").after('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeid +'" class="youtubeiframe"></iframe>');
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this more easily if you'll start to study the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make the URL as an array and than take the second to last part. For example this also works with CSS background-image.

```js
id = $('div').attr('style').split('/');
id = id[id.length-2];
alert("YouTube ID: " + id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/MHUOty8-Ty0/0.jpg');"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Wobbo/wfyL1hem/7/