# Do not display Iframe if class is not present?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, youtube

I recently asked a question on dynamically forming YouTube iframe src which was answered with a 100% working jquery for what I asked which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870113/how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-image-thumbnail-source-and-set-as-an-iframe)

but I have a problem even if `class="youtubeimg"` is not present the iframe is still there OBVIOUSLY. So what i dont know how to do is write a query If the class `class="youtubeimg"` is not present on the page then how can I get it to not display iframe with this class `class="youtubeiframe"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use css,

```
iframe {display: none;} /* hide all iframes */
iframe.youtubeimg{display:block;} /* display the one you wish to show */
```

**Edited**
Really and truthfully this should be a server side issue you gotta fix, because, even if you hide that, you still loading it, and wastes resources ...