# Get YouTube video id from thumbnail using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube, image

the Javascript below only works as for youtube videos actual url.

```
<script>
regex = /http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(\w{11})/;
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VK4ah66jBvE&feature=feedu';
id = url.match(regex)[1];
document.write(''+id+'');
</script>
```

what i dont know how to do is a regex if the url happened to be a thumbnail of a youtube video which in this example would be `http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg` ? I have tried

```
<script>
regex = /http\:\/\/i1\.ytimg\.com\/vi(\w{11})/0.jpg;;
url = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg';
id = url.match(regex)[1];
document.write(''+id+'');
</script>
```

Comment: Very similar to [how to get YouTube video id from image thumbnail source, and set as an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870113/how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-image-thumbnail-source-and-set-as-an-iframe/7870246#7870246)

Comment: no because thats jquery this is javascript. i havent mentioned or tagged jquery in this post. im having problems with the jquery as it wont work alongside another bit of jquery which is much more important. could you help me please?

Comment: The regular expression is the same, as it is using Javascript's .match()

Comment: oh :/ i dont really know jquery. I'm really good with css html and have little but good understanding of javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would this work?

```
regex = new RegExp(/\/vi\/(.*)\//);
url = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg';
id = url.match(regex)[1];
```

Comment: i have another question for you. would you know how to set the `url = '' `by extracting the src from the img tag `<img id="youtubeimg" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg"/>`

Comment: @user1010031 I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the question.  Perhaps you could make another SO question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a / and to escape a / and the trailing /

```
regex = /http\:\/\/i1\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/(\w{11})\/0.jpg/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `\/` before `(\w{11})`, then you need to escape the next slash with `\`, you should probably escape the `.`, and then you need the closing slash:

```
var regex = /http\:\/\/i1\.ytimg\.com\/vi\/(\w{11})\/0\.jpg/;
```