# Javascript : get <img> src and set as variable?

Tags: javascript, image, src

If the img below is present

```
<img id="youtubeimg" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg"/>
```

and the script is

```
<script>
var youtubeimgsrc = "something here"

document.write(''+youtubeimgsrc+'')
</script>
```

and the result should be `http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VK4ah66jBvE/0.jpg`

what can i do to get the image source and set as a variable.

Comment: A JavaScript question and not one answer using jQuery? How strange! `var youtubeimgsrc = $('youtubeimg').attr('src');`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

As long as the script is *after* the `img`, then:

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById("youtubeimg").src;
```

See [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) in the DOM specification.

If the script is *before* the `img`, then of course the `img` doesn't exist yet, and that doesn't work. This is one reason why many people recommend putting scripts at the end of the `body` element.

---

Side note: It doesn't matter in your case because you've used an absolute URL, but if you used a *relative* URL in the attribute, like this:

```
<img id="foo" src="/images/example.png">
```

...the `src` reflected property will be the *resolved* URL — that is, the absolute URL that that turns into. So if that were on the page `http://www.example.com`, `document.getElementById("foo").src` would give you `"http://www.example.com/images/example.png"`.

If you wanted the `src` attribute's content *as is*, without being resolved, you'd use `getAttribute` instead: `document.getElementById("foo").getAttribute("src")`. That would give you `"/images/example.png"` with my example above.

If you have an absolute URL, like the one in your question, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 13):

How about this for instance :

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById("youtubeimg").getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: No need for `getAttribute`, `src` is a [reflected property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-97320704) documented by the standard and supported by every browser since the mid-90's (er, not in that order ;-) ).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder correct, this was just alternative if he wanted to add custom property he could use this. Still I'd choose your answer if I was him.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `.src` and `.getAttribute('src')` return different results. First option will resolve **URL** while second option will return **src** parameter as is. Therefore this is the correct answer to question.

Comment: @Daew: They do indeed give different return values if the URL in the attribute is relative, yes. The URL in the `src` in the question is absolute, however.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree, and in most use cases it doesn't really matter which one you use. I just wanted to point out that since they return different results, this method is also relevant and not just an alias. Thanks for updating your answer =)

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have an id on the image but have a parent div this is also a technique you can use.

```
<div id="myDiv"><img src="http://www.example.com/image.png"></div>

var myVar = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv img')[0].src
```

Answer (score 0):

in this situation, you would grab the element by its id using `getElementById` and then just use `.src`

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById("youtubeimg").src;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById('youtubeimg').src;
document.write(youtubeimgsrc);
```

Here's a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/cruxst/dvrEN/

Answer (score -2):

Use JQuery, its easy.

Include the JQuery library into your html file in the head as such:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

(Make sure that this script tag goes before your other script tags in your html file)

Target your id in your JavaScript file as such:

```
<script>
var youtubeimcsrc = $('#youtubeimg').attr('src');

//your var will be the src string that you're looking for

</script>
```

Comment: ok, and even this is easy .. `document.getElementById("youtubeimg").src`? .. or may be if you just define your own function `function a(elem){ return document.getElementById(elem); }` Now this is easiest `var youtubeimgsrc = a('youtubeimg').src`