# javascript img src for any image on the page

Tags: javascript, this, image, alert, src

I'm a JS newbie - still learning. I'm looking for a solution similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable)

for displaying the source link of an image in an alert using onclick. However, I want to apply it to *any* image on the page, and there are no ID's on any of the images.  Perhaps this is an application of the mysterious 'this'? Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this has to do with delegate event listeners, and the way events spread across the DOM.

When you click on an element in the page, a `click` event is generated. For what it matters to your purposes, this event is fired on the element, and it's caught by the function you define with `onclick`.

But the event also "bubbles up" to the parent, and it's caught by the `onclick` function defined there, if any. And then to the parent of the parent, and so on.

What you have to do, now, is to catch the event on the root element, which is the `document` object itself, or maybe the `document.body` element if you still want to use `onclick` (which is deprecated).

The event object is passed to the onclick function and it contains the original element that fired the event:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (tgt.tagName === "IMG")
        alert(tgt.src);
}
```

(The `e.target || e.srcElement` part is because in IE<9 the `target` property is called `srcElement`.) That's the way you define a delegate event listener. It's not defined on the `<img>` elements, as you can see, but on their common ancestor.

But since you can define just one `click` event listener in the traditional way, I'd strongly recommend to use something more modern like the `addEventListener` method, which lets you add multiple event listeners on the same element for the same event type:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

In Internet Explorer <9 you'll have to use `attachEvent`, which is quite similar but not the same. For a cross-browser solution, use a common JS framework like jQuery, or Prototype, or whatever.

Comment: I've studied 'bubble up' but still don't have a good grasp.  I thought it meant that the event floats upwards to the highest possible parent element _and fires on every element that it passes on the way!_  Sounds like you're saying I have misunderstood, yes?

Comment: You're welcome - and sorry if I didn't provide further details back then, it seems I missed your message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question this is your solution,

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){
    alert(img[i].src);
}
```