# Change CSS code when div element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to make a little photo album for a website.
There are some small photo thumbnails on the left side. If you click one of them it should appear on the right side in full resulution. I thought you could solve this by overlapping all pictures and put them in `display: none`. Every time you click on a thumbnail image a little javascript function triggers which changes the  css of the specific picture to `display: block` to make it visible. Here's my existing code incl. JSfiddle:

```css
.images{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;}

.images img{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;}
  
.images:hover, .images:visited, .images:active {
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;}
  
.table {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  float: left;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://mgt.sjp.ac.lk/ent/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/coming-soon-bigger-600x600.jpg" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://www.drphillipscenter.org/resources/images/default.jpg" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300">
  </div>
</div>
<p>When clicked, I want the Picture to appear right here but sized bigger.</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zar2u0v1/1/

Better suggestions as hiding all the images would be nice because the lack of performance would be a problem.
Thanks in advance and I hope you can help me!

Comment: You can try yourself by changing the image `width` and `height` on `click` event of `img`.

Comment: I would personaly replace `<p>...</p>` with an `<img>` tag and set the picture link using JavaScript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable the link should be set each time the user clicks on one picture.

Comment: http://www.cssscript.com/categories/gallery/ http://www.cssscript.com/create-thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-image-preview-using-gallerly-js/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zar2u0v1/1/. little late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you in the right path.

- Use a `tabindex` for the `<div>` to make it clickable.
- Use `:focus` CSS state to style the focussed `<div>`.
- And finally `position` the image when you focus.

The good part about this is, everything is done using CSS and no JavaScript required. Plus works in IE 8 as well! `:)`

**Note:** This might mess up with your tabbing sequence.

```css
body {margin: 15px;}
.focus {cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; width: 100px; line-height: 100px; text-align: center; position: relative;}
.focus img,
.focus span {display: none;}
.focus span:first-child {display: block;}

.focus:focus {background: #f90;}
.focus:focus img,
.focus:focus span {display: block;}
.focus:focus span:first-child {display: none;}

.focus img {position: absolute; right: -150px; top: -25px; z-index: 9;}
```

```html
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me</span>
  <span>I am clicked!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Big+Image" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me</span>
  <span>I am clicked!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Big+Image" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me</span>
  <span>I am clicked!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Big+Image" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me</span>
  <span>I am clicked!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Big+Image" />
</div>
```

After understanding the issue, and requirement, I would propose another solution, which is also CSS based:

```css
body {margin: 15px; padding-right: 250px;}
.focus {cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; width: 120px; line-height: 120px; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;}
.focus img,
.focus span {display: none;}
.focus span:first-child {display: block;}

.focus:focus {background: #f90;}
.focus:focus img,
.focus:focus span {display: block;}
.focus:focus span:first-child {display: none;}

.focus img {position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px; z-index: 9;}
```

```html
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me 1</span>
  <span>You clicked 1!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/250?text=Big+Image+1" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me 2</span>
  <span>You clicked 2!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/250?text=Big+Image+2" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me 3</span>
  <span>You clicked 3!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/250?text=Big+Image+3" />
</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">
  <span>Click Me 4</span>
  <span>You clicked 4!</span>
  <img src="//placehold.it/250?text=Big+Image+4" />
</div>
```

Same effect with CSS! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Add an `<img>` tag to the `<p>` and change it's `src` based on the selected thumbnail.

**Check below example:**

```js
function show(el) {
  document.getElementById("zoom").src = el.src;
}
```

```css
.images {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
.images img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
.images:hover,
.images:visited,
.images:active {
  border: 4px solid #009EE0;
}
.table {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  float: left;
}
p {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://mgt.sjp.ac.lk/ent/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/coming-soon-bigger-600x600.jpg" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300" onclick="show(this)">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://www.drphillipscenter.org/resources/images/default.jpg" alt="DK_2014_MFK_Radtour_0168.jpg, 241kB" title="DK 2014 MFK Radtour 0168" height="auto" width="300" onclick="show(this)">
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  <img id="zoom" src="" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put css in your image the `position:relative` style so you can now set where to appear the image by using `right:(n)px`,

Or you can use also the `position:absolute` in image but don't forget to set `position:relative` in its parent.