# Assign src of image into a variable through JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, image, variables, src, assign

I want to assign content of the src tag of image to a variable on clicking on the image through JS:
Eg-

HTML

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="img">
<span id="source"/>
```

JS
???

I want to assign the image source "image.jpg" to a variable and then load it through id "source" when I click on the image in HTML. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please answer me Markus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : get <img> src and set as variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is this:

```
var src = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("src");
```

the second part is unclear

> .. and then load it through id "source" in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not really quite clear what you want to achieve. Getting the content of the src tag is pretty easy and i got that working so far. But i'm not really sure if you now want to replace the id attribute of the span tag or what.

What i've solved so far: get the src

html:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="img">
<span id="source" />
```

js:

```
var src = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("src");
document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = src;
```

Demo on: https://jsfiddle.net/6oprtnv6/

So please clarify your second part

Comment: Answer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675989/assign-src-of-image-to-a-variable-through-js-in-html