# Assign src of image to a variable through JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, image, variables, src, assign

I want to assign content of the src tag of image to a variable on clicking on the image through JS:
Eg-

HTML

```
<div id="img">
<img src="image1.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
<span id="source"/>
```

JS
???

I want to assign the image source of the clicked image to a variable and then display the source on HTML through span. This all should happen when I click the image. And the source that is going to be assigned to variable should be of the clicked image.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more likely a JavaScript question. please don't tag Java

Comment: You should at least provide a little bit of javascript code, try something before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
<html>
  <head>

  <script>
      function setImage(id){
         var element = document.getElementById(id).src;
         document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = "<img src='" +   element + "' />";
      }

  </script>

  </head>

  <body>
         <div id="img">
           <img id="img1" src="image1.jpg" onclick="setImage(this.id)" >
           <img id="img2" src="image2.jpg" onclick="setImage(this.id)" >
         </div>
        <span id="source"></span>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: But i need that this should happen when I click the image!

Comment: in this example, when you click on an image (image1 or image2), that particular image will be shown in span... isn't it you want?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
<img ng-src="{{myVar}}">
```

Comment: What will this do?

Comment: from angular controller you can assing value to myvar.

Comment: At no point does the question asker state that they are using AngularJS. Please ready the question thoroughly before providing an answer, and provide some [context surrounding your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) to state how your code should be implemented (such as that it requires AngularJS in this case). I also recommend reviewing the [help article on how to write great answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :)