# Get link of clicked image pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

</body>
</html>
```

i want to get the image source in java script when any image is clicked and ovveride(ignore) the onclick attribute for any image (if available)

- Note: i cant change anything in the HTML code
- Note2: i can only use pure JavaScript (no jQuery or anything else)
- Note3: the image does not have an ID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : get <img> src and set as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable)

Comment: this is not a duplicate i dont have the id and i cant edit the html in my case

Comment: Then ask a question about how to get an element when you don't have an id (better yet, google how to do so), this one is still a dupe of the one in the link and should be closed.

Comment: @JaredSmith, he did say that the image has no id though...i agree that it should be closed anyways.

Comment: @doutriforce there are actually two questions here: "how do I get an element that has no id" and "how do I get the `src` attribute of an image tag". Both are dupes. Combining them doesn't really make them not dupes.

Comment: @JaredSmith, i'm not saying that it's not a dupe.

Comment: @doutriforce oh, I'm not trying to argue with you, I'm just explaining the rationale behind my VTC. I probably should have used a custom close reason to link to both questions.

Comment: @JaredSmith, no problem, me neither.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one image, then

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(img[0].src);
```

To get all the src of images,

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i = 0;i < img.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(img[i].src);
    }
```

To get the clicked image src,

```
   document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e = e || window.event; 
     var target = e.target; 
     if(target.tagName == 'IMG'){ console.log(target.src); }
    }, false);
```

Comment: To get the clicked image,

`document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target;
 if(target.tagName == 'IMG'){
     console.log(target.src);
        }
}, false);`

Comment: thanks for the replay, your code works great !
i was just wondering is it possible to ignore onclick tag of ,the image ?

Comment: simplest way is

    `var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(i = 0;i < img.length; i++)
    {
        img[i].onclick = '';
        console.log(img[i].src);
    }`

Comment: sorry to bother you again but this code   document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e = e || window.event; 
     var target = e.target; 
     if(target.tagName == 'IMG'){ console.log(target.src); }
    }, false);

is logging the same url for all images in the webpage, any ideas ?