# How to get image src in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML image tag with the source blank. The source will change based on input type file when the user uploads an image. So how do I get the image source? I can't hardcode the source as it will change based on what the user selects.So i want to retrieve the image src based on the file user has selected.
Here are the codes i used:

i want to get the image directory by retrieving image src so i can check if there's an XML file created in the folder which has the same name as the image.
thank you

Comment: show  some code please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change the src of an img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag)

Comment: Please share the code how you are calling this function readURL(input); And html for input type file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : get <img> src and set as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable)

Comment: @Eitbiz hi i have added the code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the PHP code you are specifically asking for is

`$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`

However, take a look at the [tutorial from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

HTML upload form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Php uploader

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```