# unable to change image source in DOM javascript

Tags: javascript

I’m Rahul and I’m new to coding. I have a query related to DOM event. Please look at the following code snippet -

```js
let door1 = document.getElementById('one');
door1.src = "closed_door.svg";
const isClicked = (door) => {
    if(door.src === "closed_door.svg") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
door1.onclick = () => {
    if(isClicked(door1)) {
    door1.src = "beach.svg";}
};
```

To give you brief, one is an id for an element. Without isClicked, I am able to successfully change the src from closed door to beach on clicking. But when I introduce isClick, it doesn’t change. Can someone please tell me what I’m missing. I’ll be very thankful

Note - I'm building game similar to this - https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/chore-door-final/index.html They are using the same process as mine. So please suggest a solution that tells me about the error I'm making here rather than an alternative to the problem

Regards
Rahul

Comment: `console.log(door.src)` in the isClicked method and see what it says it is

Comment: It's better to use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` when modifying attributes that appear directly in the html. Change `door1.src = 'closed_door.svg';` into `door1.setAttribute('src', 'closed_door.svg');`. Change `if (door.src === 'closed_door.svg')` into `if (door.getAttribute('src') === 'closed_door.svg')`

Comment: My assumption is the logic needs to be changed to `door.src.endsWith('closed_door.svg')`

Comment: Please make [mre]

Comment: Thank you Gershom, your suggestion worked perfectly! But can you tell me my mistake? What exactly is causing error in my code?

Comment: The `src` on the door Element is the property of the element, not the attribute.  The property most likely has the full file path.  The attribute may be 'me.svg', but the property will probably be 'https://yoursite.com/me.svg`.  This is why I said to log the value and see for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882379/12361700):

> the src reflected property will be the resolved URL — that is, the absolute URL that that turns into. So if that were on the page http://www.example.com, document.getElementById("foo").src would give you "http://www.example.com/images/example.png".

so to get the real `src` attribute you should use `.getAttribute('src')` like so:

```
const isClicked = (door) => {
    if(door.getAttribute('src') === "closed_door.svg") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Ans also BTW, you can just shortcut it to:

```
const isClicked = (door) => door.getAttribute('src') === "closed_door.svg";
```

Comment: Thank you Berto. Just a query - https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/chore-door-final/index.html

They use the similar logic as mine. Can you tell me the mistake why I cannot get similar results with the logic I gave in the snippet?

Comment: @Rahul  because they have `let closedDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg"` and not `let closedDoorPath = "closed_door.svg"`

Comment: Thank you so much @Berto99. This was my first question on Stack Overflow and you made a very pleasant experience for me! Means a lot for a learner like me who is currently on zero level! Please be a savior in the future as well! :D

Comment: @Rahul ahah sure no problem, we all passed by that moment, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this..

```
let door1 = document.getElementById('one');
door1.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg";
const isClicked = (door1) => {
    if(door1.src === "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

door1.onclick = () => {
    if(isClicked(door1)) {
    door1.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/beach.svg";}
};
```

Comment: Incorrect solution. Please check the answer by berto99

Comment: Okay .. .. @Rahul