# I've got a javascript array and want to call images by name

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I am an object oriented programming dev who's getting extremely frustrated with web languages.
Here's the thing...
I have an array in javascript that looks somewhat like this after a split:

```
imgArr [1, 6, 0, 2.......]
```

This is not a static array but something I am reading from a variable source, meaning sometimes the array will have a different number of entries.

My goal is simple, I want to add as many image sources as array entries are and replace the image source name by these numbers in the array.

My usual approach to this would be to do something like:

```
<img src=("img/userpics/" + ${imgArr{i}} + ".png");
```

inside an incremental for, but this doesn't seem possible or if it is, I really don't know how nor can I find how to do it.

How can I proceed? Can anybody please help this poor web dev illiterate?

Comment: are you using a frontend framework?? you should call array members by `imgArr[i]`...
plus if you are using javascript template strings you should do it like ``img/userpics/${imgArr[i]}.png``

Comment: i could not type the syntax right in the previous comment. if you want to use the template strings you should use ` instead of ". with your current syntax you should remove ${} from your src attribute.
read more about template strings in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: No, my knowledge of web is really limited (did laravel many years ago but almost remember nothing) so I went without a framework, just notepad++ and studio code now since things got a bit more complicated along the way. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I'll check that template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about the context, here's how I would think to map that:

```js
const imgArr = [5, 9, 2, 0, 1, ...]

const images = imgArr.map(n => `<img src="img/userpics/${n}.png" />`)
```

A lot depends on what framework you're in and what the context and scope are here, but this would be how I would take an array of integers and map them to `img` tags in string form.  If you're using React, you would do:

```
const images = imgArr.map(n => <img src={`img/userpics/${n}.png`} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. But for your purpose, I would do it this way

```
<img id= "myId" src=("img/userpics/1.png")/>
```

and js

```
let myImgSrc = document.getElementById("myId").src;
```

then I can push myImgSrc to array or anything, and loop through and do whatever to it. check this one:

[Javascript : get <img> src and set as variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable)