# Get youtubeID from youtube image

Tags: php, youtube

I have this youtube image link " http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/W3r-GMq4PZc/0.jpg ". I want to get youtube id only. How to get only youtubeID by using PHP?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: I want to get youtube id by using PHP language. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at questions in the search? 
Found this: 
[how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-image-thumbnail-source-and-set-as-an-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870113/how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-image-thumbnail-source-and-set-as-an-iframe)

You can also use PHP RegExp to extract this is you want:

```
$subject = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/W3r-GMq4PZc/0.jpg";
$pattern = '/[\w\-]{11,}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

source: [Php preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, tanks :)